# How to print invoice directly in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, printing

I am currently working on asp.net c# Project on POS (Point Of Sale). I am using JavaScript function on page load but it populate print dialogue box in google chrome. This is my page load JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {`enter code here`
            window.print();

        }

</script>
```

I don't want this Google Chrome print dialog box. How can in print invoice directly on button click? I am stuck at this point.

What I have tried: I used JavaScript function. I want some C# function which directly print the invoice.

Answer (score 0):

You may have **alternate way**.

- Save items in database, which you wants to print.
- Run window service, which collect this printable item and print in back end.